# ASP.Net MVC returning 404 for generated JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, webpack

ASP.Net MVC project is not able to serve js in wwwroot/js folder (generated by webpack).

I'm getting a 404 when page is trying to access js/app.js.

The csproj has an itemgroup for wwwroot like this, but it appears it isn't copied. How do I get it copied over?

```
  <ItemGroup>
     <None Update="wwwroot\**">
         <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

---

This is what my Program.cs contains.

```
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Extensions.MsDependencyInjection;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8;
using React.AspNet;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddReact();
builder.Services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => options.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName)
  .AddV8();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseReact(config =>
{
    config
      .SetLoadBabel(false)
      .AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/js/app.js");
});

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
});

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

---

My index.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
  <title>CivicSpace</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/app.js")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[UPDATE]

Not sure what the issue was. I created a new ASP.Net MVC project where js is loading correctly, and moved my code over. The .csproj didn't need to declare how the js file is to be handled. It worked.

Comment: could you show how you refered app.js in your view?

Comment: I call it like this <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/app.js")"></script> (updated post with index.cshtml.)

Comment: The problem may be with not copying wwwroot, but I have an ItemGroup for it.

Comment: I thought when mixing Razor and script tags you had to use different quotes, like: <script src='@Url.Content("~/js/app.js")'></script> otherwise the razor render engine gets confused? could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the property of js file is not same with the tag"None",Have you tried as below?

[image]

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Content Update="wwwroot/js/app.js">
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreServeNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the entire folder in your build output:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*.*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```